# How to change button background when pressed on HTML5

Tags: css, html

I am developing an HTML5 web page for mobile. On mobile device, we can't detect hover event. So, how to change the background of button when I press it by my finger?

Update: One simple example of what I want is the button "Google Search" of google main page: https://www.google.com.vn/

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution as below. Hope this helps

```
button:ACTIVE {
    background: aqua;
}

button {
    background: green;
}
```